# Comparison of 2 numbers using one

Tags: calculus

Would like to ask if it is possible to do this:

I have a set of several pair of numbers, say (x,y). The first numbers x are always in increasing number of each other, and so is the 2nd number y in the pairs.

Eg:
Pair(x,y)
A: (1000,10)
B: (2000,20)
C: (10000,30)
D: (50000,60)

I have now some pairs of numbers E to J, and for each given pair I must compare and find the first pair of numbers A to D, such that both the x1 and y1 is less than or equal to the corresponding numbers in the pair (from A to D).

Eg
Given Pair(x1,y1) => Answer 
E: (500,8)  => A 
F: (1000,8)  => A
G: (1000,12) => B
H: (2000,12) => B 
I: (500,20) => B 
J: (10000,8) => C

It would be easy to compare the pairs of x and y to find the answer. However is there any way to combine/concat/merge the x,y using a formula to a single number (say z) such that the comparison can be done just once?

Eg: I use z = x*y
Pair(x,y,z)
A: (1000,10,10000)
B: (2000,20,40000)
C: (10000,30,300000)
D: (50000,60,300000)

-Apply same formula to given pairs: z1=x1*y1
Given Pair(x1,y1,z1) => Answer 
E: (500,8,4000)  => A 
F: (1000,8,8000)  => A
G: (1000,12,12000) => B
H: (2000,12,24000) => B 
I: (500,20,1000) => A  -> Wrong, correct answer should be B since (y1=20) > (yA=10)
J: (10000,8,80000) => C

and then just compare the z values to get the answer. (first pair from given pairs of numbers A to D where the corresponding z values is lower or equal to the calculated z1).

In the above example z= x*y cannot work as the answer for pair I is wrong. The calculated z value for pair I is 1000 < value of z for A, but answer should be b since y value of pair I is more than y value of pair A.

Hope that my explanation is clear and hope any experts here can tell me if its possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) $\pi(k_1, k_2) = \frac{1}{2}(k_1 + k_2)(k_1 + k_2 + 1) + k_2$. It doesn't quite have the properties you want (if $\pi(a,b) \leq \pi(c,d)$, all that's guaranteed is that $a + b \leq c + d$) but you might be able to make it work.

One thing to note is that there *is* no function that works exactly the way you want it to, simply because of incompatibilities in ordering. What I mean is, single numbers are "linearly" ordered - given $n$ and $m$, it's always the case that either $n \leq m$ or $m \leq n$. But pairs aren't; $(2,3)$ isn't "before" or "after" $(3,2)$ in the ordering you described. So if we devised a way to compress each of these into a single number, we'd have to get a "false positive" - either we'd think $(2,3) \leq (3,2)$ or $(3,2) \leq (2,3)$.